# How to indent grep's output?

Tags: grep, indentation

I need grep's output to be indented with tabs/spaces.

This is the plain, un-indented version:  `MyCmd | grep "id:"`

I tried this without success:`MyCmd | grep "id:" | echo "   "`

Comment: Such questions shall always come with example input and example output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with `awk` instead of `grep` if that's acceptable:

```
MyCmd | awk '/id:/ {print "   " $0}'
```

or if you need grep, `sed` could help:

```
MyCmd | grep "id:" | sed -e 's/^/   /'
```

The `awk` version does its own pattern match for lines that contain "id:" and then will print the spaces before the line.  The `sed` version does the `grep` as you already did it but then replaces the start of each line (regex `^` matches the start of a line) with the spaces

Answer (score 3):

Use just `sed` instead:

```
MyCmd | sed 's/^.*id:/\t&/'
```

The will match `id:` and introduce a tab at the start of the matched lines.

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/^foo/\t&/' <<<'foobar' 
    foobar
```